# How Do I set values in Blazorise Datagrid CustomFilter?

Tags: filter, datagrid, blazorise

I am trying to add a Custom Filter to my Blazorise Data Grid column.  Currently I can type in values, and it begins to filter with each typed value.  I would like the filter values to be based on existing values from the context object in a drop down.  Below is the code I have so far, I just need a little help with configuring the Custom Filter if this is possible.

```razor
@page "/Loadinglist"
@using myDB.Data

<DataGrid TItem="LoadData"
          Data="@loadList"
          @bind-SelectedRow="@selectedLoad"
          Editable="true"
          Resizable
          Filterable
          FilterMethod="DataGridFilterMethod.StartsWith"
          Responsive="true"
          Striped="true"
          ShowPager="true"
          ShowPageSizes="true"
          CommandMode="DataGridCommandMode.ButtonRow"
          EditMode="editMode">
    <DataGridColumns>
        <DataGridColumn Field="@nameof(LoadData.id)" Caption="#" Sortable="true" />
        <DataGridColumn Field="@nameof(LoadData.caliber)" Caption="Caliber" Editable  />  @*<---Trying to use queryAllCalibers as source to custom filter*@
    </DataGridColumns>
</DataGrid>

@code {
    [Inject]
    public GetLoadData? getLoadData { get; set; }

    private IEnumerable<LoadData>? loadList;
    private IEnumerable<string> queryAllCalibers;
    private LoadData? selectedLoad;
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        loadList = await getLoadData.GetDataAsync();
        GetCalibersFromContext();
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
    protected void GetCalibersFromContext()
    {
        //Existing values in the context
        queryAllCalibers = (from calibers in loadList
                            select calibers.caliber).Distinct();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `<FilterTemplate>` on `DataGridColumn`:

```razor
<DataGridColumn CustomFilter="@OnCaliberCustomFilter" Field="@nameof(LoadData.caliber)" Caption="Caliber" Editable>
    <FilterTemplate>
        <Select TValue="string" SelectedValue="@selectedCaliberFilter" SelectedValueChanged="@(value => { selectedCaliberFilter = value; context.TriggerFilterChange(selectedCaliberFilter); })">
            <SelectItem Value="@("*")">All</SelectItem>
            @foreach(var caliber in queryAllCalibers)
            {
                <SelectItem Value="@caliber">@caliber</SelectItem>
            }
        </Select>
    </FilterTemplate>
</DataGridColumn>

@code {
    private string? selectedCaliberFilter;

    private bool OnCaliberCustomFilter(object itemValue, object searchValue)
    {
        if (searchValue is string caliberFilter)
        {
            return caliberFilter == "*" || caliberFilter == itemValue?.ToString();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Check [DataGrid: Features -> Custom Column Filtering](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/features)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have been parsing it out to see how it works. My version was missing the return * and my SelectedValueChanged anonyms method was completely wrong. I am running into a new problem. The code that populates the queryAllCalibers collection is not getting fired off so its Null. I'll keep looking at it. I'm sure once I get that figured out your answer will do exactly what I want it to do.